# jQuery, .each() and children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find and set the first option of many select boxes on a page.

```
$('ul#mygroup li select').each(function () {
  $(this +' option:nth-child(0)').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

The second line is where this is failing at.  I can't seem to target the first option of each select box within the group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `.each()`; just do this:

```
$('#mygroup li select option:first-of-type').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: using jQuery prop() would be more accurate

Answer (score 3):

You're misusing selectors.

You need to write `$(this).children('option:first-child').attr('selected', true)`.

You can also just write `$('ul#mygroup li select').prop('selectedIndex', 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't be concatenating `this`, you should be using it for *scope*.

```
$('option:first',this).attr('selected','selected');
```

Or, concisely you're saying (keeping it within the `.each` loop)

```
$(this).find('option:first').attr('selected','selected');
```

Though, as others have mentioned, there's no need to use the `.each`. In fact, `nth-child` is specifically there to *avoid* using an `.each`

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$('ul#mygroup li select').each(function () {
  $(this).children('option').first().attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```
<select name="type1">
    <option value="1">Option 1</value>
    <option value="2">Option 2</value>
    <option value="3">Option 3</value>    
</select>

<select name="type2">
    <option value="1">Option 1</value>
    <option value="2">Option 2</value>
    <option value="3">Option 3</value>    
</select>        

<select name="type3">
    <option value="1">Option 1</value>
    <option value="2">Option 2</value>
    <option value="3">Option 3</value>    
</select>     


$(function(){
    $('select').each(function () {
        $(this).children().first().attr('selected', 'selected');
        $(this).children().first().attr('style', 'color: blue');
    });
});
```